# Is it possible to have tabs without javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to have a box with tabs, and have found many tutorials on how it's done with javascript to switch between the tabs. Is there anyway to have tabs without javascript?

Comment: You must be crazy. You can't do anything interesting without Javascript. Geez. (Of course, I am being [facetious](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/facetious).)

Comment: And it's not really an "answer" to say Google has some links to content... Answer the d*** question, or post a comment.

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML tab interface using only CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937371/html-tab-interface-using-only-css)

Answer (score 21):

EDIT: As of 2020 this technique still works and allows tabs to be linked to, but if you are looking for multiple tabsets on one page, see @chulian's answer which uses `input[type=radio]` instead of `:target`.

There is an archive of the now-dead html5rockstars.com demo here: 
https://web.archive.org/web/20121118201357/http://htmlrockstars.com/blog/using-css-to-create-a-tabbed-content-area-no-js-required/

The same technique is covered, arguably better, here: 
http://www.sitepoint.com/css3-tabs-using-target-selector/

What it boils down to is that you use the CSS3 `:target` selector to unhide whichever tab is currently selected. This will only work if there is only one set of tabs on the page, but has the advantage of complete browser back button support. For example:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="#tab1">First tab</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab2">Second tab</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab3">Third tab</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="tab1" class="tab-content">Content of first tab</div>
<div id="tab2" class="tab-content">Content of second tab</div>
<div id="tab3" class="tab-content">Content of third tab</div>
```

And then in your stylesheet:

```
.tab-content {
    display: none;
}
.tab-content:target {
    display: block;
}
```

Unfortunately this isn't perfect, as no tab content will show up until one of the links is clicked (unless you link to `page.html#tab1`). The second link above suggests something like the following as a solution to that issue:

```
.tab-content {
    z-index: 0;
    background-color: white;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
}
.tab-content:first-child {
    z-index: 1;
}
.tab-content:target {
    z-index: 2;
}
```

This is somewhat hackish, and also requires absolute positioning.

As an alternative, if you do not mind having your default tab be last in the html (you can order the links however you like, of course), you could do this:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="#tab1">First tab</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab2">Second tab</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab3">Third tab</a></li>
</ul>
    <div class="tab-folder">
    <div id="tab2" class="tab-content">Content of second tab</div>
    <div id="tab3" class="tab-content">Content of third tab</div>
    <div id="tab1" class="tab-content">Content of first tab</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.tab-folder > .tab-content:target ~ .tab-content:last-child, .tab-folder > .tab-content {
    display: none;
}
.tab-folder > :last-child, .tab-folder > .tab-content:target {
    display: block;
}
```

This is arguably the cleanest solution and the one that I would choose over the others, unless I suspected that many people would be visiting my page with CSS turned off.

Comment: With your last solution, sometimes all the tabs end up hidden. This only happens when posting data with Ajax, however, I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: @DanBray, I can't imagine why that would happen as a result of an HTTP request. Something must be wrong with the code that updates the DOM after the request has completed. This tab solution is pure-CSS, so it is unlikely that anything else would cause it to fail.

Answer (score 15):

Found this one, hope it solves your question

http://css-tricks.com/functional-css-tabs-revisited/

demo: http://css-tricks.com/examples/CSSTabs/radio.php

```
<div class="tabs">

   <div class="tab">
       <input type="radio" id="tab-1" name="tab-group-1" checked>
       <label for="tab-1">Tab One</label>

       <div class="content">
           stuff
       </div> 
   </div>

   <div class="tab">
       <input type="radio" id="tab-2" name="tab-group-1">
       <label for="tab-2">Tab Two</label>

       <div class="content">
           stuff
       </div> 
   </div>

    <div class="tab">
       <input type="radio" id="tab-3" name="tab-group-1">
       <label for="tab-3">Tab Three</label>

       <div class="content">
           stuff
       </div> 
   </div>

</div>
```

css

```
.tabs {
  position: relative;   
  min-height: 200px; /* This part sucks */
  clear: both;
  margin: 25px 0;
}
.tab {
  float: left;
}
.tab label {
  background: #eee; 
  padding: 10px; 
  border: 1px solid #ccc; 
  margin-left: -1px; 
  position: relative;
  left: 1px; 
}
.tab [type=radio] {
  display: none;   
}
.content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 28px;
  left: 0;
  background: white;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc; 
}
[type=radio]:checked ~ label {
  background: white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  z-index: 2;
}
[type=radio]:checked ~ label ~ .content {
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: This is the best solution of all. I work on Angular, and I had a page that is updated through HTML code entered on a back office. This is the only solution that worked by sanitizing the code and using Angular Pipes. Fantastic. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

This method is slightly different from the `:target` method, using overflow and named anchors instead. The benefit is that your CSS doesn't need to know anything about dynamic content. Generated markup only needs to match

`<a href="#myFirstTab">Tab A</a>` in the navigation with

`<a name="myFirstTab"></a>` inside the tab itself (at the end, preferably)

```css
.ContentArea{ 
  width: 50vw;
  height: 50vh;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 25vh;
  left: 25vw;
  overflow: hidden;
 }
.tab{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
.clearance{
  
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Tab Sandbox</title>
<body>

  <nav class="ribbon">
    <a href="#tab1">A</a> | 
    <a href="#tab2">B</a> | 
    <a href="#tab3">C</a> | 
    <a href="#tab4">D</a> | 
    <a href="#tab5">E</a>
    <a href="#tab6">F</a>
  </nav>
  <div class="ContentArea"> 
    
    <div class="tab">
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa <br/>
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa <br/>
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa <br/>
      <div class="clearance">
        <a name="tab1"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab">
    bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb <br/>
    bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb <br/>
    bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb <br/>
    bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb <br/>
    bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb <br/>
      <div class="clearance">
        <a name="tab2"></a>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="tab">
    cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc <br/>
    cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc <br/>
    cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc <br/>
    cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc <br/>
      <div class="clearance">
        <a name="tab3"></a>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="tab">
    dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd <br/>
    dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd <br/>
    dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd <br/>
    dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd <br/>
      <div class="clearance">
        <a name="tab4"></a>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="tab">
    eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee <br/>
    eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee <br/>
    eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee <br/>
    eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee <br/>
      <div class="clearance">
        <a name="tab5"></a>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="tab">
    ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff <br/>
    ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff <br/>
    ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff <br/>
    ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff <br/>

      <div class="clearance">
        <a name="tab6"></a>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</body>
</head>
</html>
```

This is nice, for one, because it only uses three simple CSS selectors and they are ALL classes. No strict requirements that come with IDs

The basic idea is you create a viewport with known dimensions, positioned either relatively or absolutely, somewhere on the page. This will be the display area for your tabs. Now you clip overflow to hide all but the first tab, rather than `display: none`

This faces a few challenges, so you may notice the "clearance" div at the end of each tab actually holds the named anchor. This div helps ensure that content is pushed around properly and not partly scrolled into view. Occasionally needs small tweaks, always very simple based on your design needs.

If you like, the nav links can be embedded in radio buttons to detect "checked" status. I've also done it where the nav is simply repeated in each tab with the active class varied. While redundant, it presents an interest navigation which can be dynamic per-tile, giving a 2D space. Fun to play with, but usually I just opt for toggling a class in the nav with jQuery.toggle()