# Toggle tab navigation without using jquery and javascript

Tags: java, css, jsp

I want to navigate between menu tabs and display content without using any java script and j query .

because, when java script disabled from the browser its does not work.

I have attached image for menu tab.

can anybody help

Thanks 
Sanjeev

Comment: What tabs? What doesn't work? Your question doesn't really say much! Maybe you can describe, give examples of what doesn't work? And how it should work?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to have tabs without javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6906724/is-it-possible-to-have-tabs-without-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my answer here: [Is it possible to have tabs without javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6906724/is-it-possible-to-have-tabs-without-javascript/6907068#6907068)

Yes, it's possible, but it won't work everywhere (yet!)

Comment: please tell how it is possible.

Comment: Please click my link!  [Or this one.](http://htmlrockstars.com/blog/using-css-to-create-a-tabbed-content-area-no-js-required/)

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't going to use javascript, then you are pretty much stuck having each tab be a link that refreshes the whole page, with the new tab marked somehow as active and its content included.