# readding items to the list while switching between navigations(firebase)

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I try to render items that are in my firestore database. It displays correctly on the first render but when I switch between tabs/navigations it will readd the data to the list again. If I keep on switching between the tabs it will add more and more.

When I use local state there is no issue with that but the issue is with when I use dispatch to display items it will readd more items to the list(not the firestore database).

```
useEffect(
    () =>
      onSnapshot(collection(db, "users"), (snapshot) => {
        console.log(
          "snapshot",
          snapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data())
        );

        const firebaseData = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data());

        dispatch(addItem(firebaseData));
        setLocalState(firebaseData);
      }),
    []
  );
```

`itemsSlice.js`

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = {
  items: [],
};

const itemsSlice = createSlice({
  name: "addItems",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    addItem: (state, action) => {
      state.items.push(...action.payload);
    },
    emptyItems: (state) => {
      state.items = [];
    },
  },
});

export const { addItem, emptyItems } = itemsSlice.actions;
export default itemsSlice.reducer;
```

Here is a gif of the issue:
https://gyazo.com/bf033f2362d9d38e9eb315845971e224

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I don't understand how you're switching between tabs, I can't tell you why the component seems to be rerendering. The `useEffect` hook is responsible to act like both the `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate` methods. And the global redux state is not going to reset itself after each render (which is why it's so great).
This is not the case for a component's state which well reset each time a component is removed from and added to the dom. This explains why when you use a local state, the problem disappears. It's not that its fixed, it's because the state is reset every time the component is removed and added (which is what seems to be happening here).
Since we don't have the full details a quick fix should be to replace this

```
state.items.push(...action.payload);
```

with this

```
state.items = [...action.payload];
```

this will set a new value to `state.items` instead of pushing to it.

Comment: This worked thanks. But I think this mutates the state which I can't seem to add a new item to the list and render the whole list.

Comment: I think it'll save you a good amount of time to look into better tab switching :) How are you currently switching tabs? Are you using traditional methods or do you fire a setState each time you switch tabs?

Comment: I use react router. I don't use any setState to switch between tabs. Here is a sample code:
```<div>
      <Navbar />
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={SignIn} />
        <Route path="/bookmarks" component={Bookmarks} />
        <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />
      </Switch>
    </div>```

Comment: Yes, but since the functional component is removed from and added to the dom on each route, the useEffect will still fire when you add it. You can use just simple html tabs if you want. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6906724/is-it-possible-to-have-tabs-without-javascript 
You should fix this "issue" as soon as you can, imagine reading from db each time a user switches tab. It'll cost you a fortune and it'll cost the user performance.

Comment: That makes sense. I haven't thought of reading data and I'm reading about 13k for literally nothing. This consumes a lot of data. I will take a look at it. Thank you.

Comment: I added the code in App.js then it prevents reading the data after switching between tabs and fixed the readding items to the list. It also fixed the issue when I try to add an item to the list.