# Creating tabs in HTML only

Tags: html

Is there is a basic way to create multiple content tabs in an HTML page without CSS and/or Javascript and/or JQuery?

Comment: StackOverflow is not the proper place for this question. You need to do your own coding and if you aren't sure why something is not working as expected, post the code with an explanation of what you were expecting it to do, and what it is actually doing including all error messages. See [about StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/about).

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML tab interface using only CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937371/html-tab-interface-using-only-css)

Comment: Not possible, CSS3 has it, jQuery has it. HTML doesn't

Comment: Oops, misread the question. Possible in CSS+HTML, not HTML only. Also, I'm not sure why anyone would want to other than idle curiosity (are you really not going to style the page at all?).

Comment: HTML is the semantics of your website. when u say you want to have a tabbing behaviour, you are talking about behaviour to change something when a link or something else is clicked and to show different content accordingly. You will need javascript to achieve this, as remember, to give behaviour to your semantics/content you need JS in browser world for clientside

Answer (score 1):

I do not think it is possible. JQuery would be my best bet at doing it since implementation is easy. you can have a look at JQUERYUI. There are other javascript library that can help you easily achieve what you want. My next choice would be CSS

Comment: why has this been down voted?

Comment: I dont know who gave him -1 but he's right. +1.