# How can I make tabs with only CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm looking to make a tab system like [jQuery tabs](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/), where users can between toggle different panels to view different content:

[image]

However, I need to accomplish this without the use of javascript, so that users without javascript enabled can easily use the site. Furthermore, I'd like to avoid navigating to different static `html` pages, each with a different style corresponding to the "tab." What's a good way to approach this?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder What about duplicates? While the answer isn't nearly as detailed/specific, a quick search brings up this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4937615/1253479 (from 2011). I could understand a Q/A from OP, if the question was "[unique](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18365315/1253479)", but I don't see the benefit of this specific post.

Comment: @royhowie: Odd, that *used* to work.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

An easy way to implement CSS-only tabs is to use radio buttons!

The key is to style `labels` that are attached to a respective button. The radio buttons themselves are hidden, with a little absolute positioning, off the side of the screen.

The basic html structure is:

```
div#holder
    input[type="radio"]
    div.content-holder
        label
        div.tab-content (all your tab content goes here)
    input[type="radio"]
    ... keep repeating
```

The key is in the selectors. We are going to style the `input[type="radio"]` buttons with

```
input[type="radio"] {
    position: absolute;
    left: -100%;
    top: -100%;
    height: 0;
    display: none;
}
```

This hoists them off the side of the screen, as mentioned above. But how do we click them then? Fortunately, if you target a `label`, it can click the input for you!

```
<label for="radioInputId1">tab title</label>
```

Then we style the actual labels (I'm going to leave out the aesthetic styling for brevity):

```
input[type="radio"] + div.content-holder > label {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    height: 35px;
    width: 33%; /* or whatever width you want */
}
```

Now our labels should look like "tabs" at the top of the `div#holder`. But what about all that content? Well, we want it to all be hidden by default, so we can target it with the following selector:

```
input[type="radio"] + div.content-holder > div.tab-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 65px;        /* this depends on your label height */
    width: 100%;
}
```

The above CSS is the minimal CSS required to get it working. Everything other than `display: none;` is what you will see when the `div` is actually displayed. But this shows nothing in the tabs, so… now what?

```
input[type="radio"]:checked + div.content-holder > div.tab-content {
    display: block;
}
```

The reason the above works is because of the `:checked` pseudo-class. Since the `label`s are attached to a specific radio button, they trigger `:checked` on click. This automatically turns all the other radio buttons off. Because we have have wrapped everything within a `div.content-holder`, we can use the next sibling CSS selector, `+`, to make sure we only target a specific tab. (Try using `~` and see what happens!)

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Luxelin/xsr96u3m/3/), for those of you who don't like stack snippets, and here's a stack snippet, for those of you who do:

```css
#holder {
  border: solid 1px black;
  display: block;
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
  width: 600px;
}
p {
  margin: 5px 0 0 5px;
}
input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
  height: 0;
  left: -100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: -100%;
}
input[type="radio"] + div.content-holder > label {
  background-color: #7BE;
  border-radius: 2px;
  color: #333;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  height: 35px;
  margin: 5px 0 0 2px;
  padding: 15px 0 0 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 33%;
}
input[type="radio"] + div.content-holder > div {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top: 65px;
  width: 100%;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked + div.content-holder > div {
  display: block;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked + div.content-holder > label {
  background-color: #B1CF6F;
}
img {
  left: 0;
  margin: 15px auto auto auto;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="holder">
  <input type="radio" name="tabs" value="1" id="check1" checked>
  <div class="content-holder">
    <label for="check1">one</label>
    <div class="tab-content">
      <p>All my content for the first tab goes here.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="radio" name="tabs" value="2" id="check2">
  <div class="content-holder">
    <label for="check2">two</label>
    <div class="tab-content">
      <h2>You can put whatever you want in your tabs!</h2>
      <p>Any content, anywhere!</p>
      <p>
        Remember, though, they're absolutely positioned.
        This means they position themselves relative to
        their parent, div#holder, which is relatively positioned
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="radio" name="tabs" value="3" id="check3">
  <div class="content-holder">
    <label for="check3">three</label>
    <div class="tab-content">
      <p>
        And maybe I want a picture of a nice cat in my third tab!
      </p>
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bgaea.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The tabs I styled are really rather basic. If you want them to "wrap" into the content, you can do that with a little extra CSS legwork.