# How to hide all other elements but show :target using only CSS (without JS)?

Tags: html, css, show-hide, target

I have 3 paragraphs and 3 links, connected between by anchors.
Every content (1,2 and 3) are visible - has

`display: block`.
I need to hide every content elements (using `display: none`) except this clicked.
Showing works with using **css `:target`** selector in situation when all elements are hidden before clicking, but it must be visible.

**Using JS is forbidden!** :(

I tried using something like **`:not(:target)`** but unfortunately it's not working. How to do this?

https://jsfiddle.net/qzd7f1or/1/

```css
.someClass {
  display: block;
}

.someClass:not(::target) {
  display: none;
}

:target {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<p><a href="#element1">Show only content 1</a></p>
<p><a href="#element2">Show only content 2</a></p>
<p><a href="#element3">Show only content 3</a></p>

<p id="element1" class="someClass"><b>Content 1...</b></p>
<p id="element2" class="someClass"><b>Content 2...</b></p>
<p id="element3" class="someClass"><b>Content 3...</b></p>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML tab interface using only CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937371/html-tab-interface-using-only-css)

Comment: It's `:target`, not `::target`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target

Comment: Yes, :target, but using :not(:target) I get blank page with error.

Answer (score 3):

This approach uses only CSS and applies `display: none` to every `someClass` element that was not targeted.

```css
:target {
  display: block;
}
.someClass:not(:target) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<p><a href="#element1">Show only content 1</a></p>
<p><a href="#element2">Show only content 2</a></p>
<p><a href="#element3">Show only content 3</a></p>

<p id="element1" class="someClass"><b>Content 1...</b></p>
<p id="element2" class="someClass"><b>Content 2...</b></p>
<p id="element3" class="someClass"><b>Content 3...</b></p>
```

Comment: Not works correctly, but every content elements must be visible at first. After click for example link 3, content 1 and 2 should be hidden.

Comment: Hmmm ok. Are you sure you can't use javascript?? Due to the nature of the current CSS, the `display: none` is taking importance. I will update my answer when I get it working correctly.

Comment: No, I can't. It's forbidden by client.